# How fast does this summation grow?

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

$n,i\in\mathbb N$.

The summation in question is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{l=1}^k\binom{2^n}{2^l}^i.$$

How fast does this grow? I am specifically looking at $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us obtain the asymptotic of $\log S_n$, where $\log$ denotes the base-$2$ logarithm,
\begin{equation*}
    S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{l=1}^k\binom{2^n}{2^l}^i
    =\sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k}, 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    a_{n,k}:=\prod_{l=1}^k\binom{2^n}{2^l}^i. 
\end{equation*}

For $k=1,\dots,n-1$,
\begin{equation*}
    r_k:=\frac{a_{n,k+1}}{a_{n,k}}=\binom{2^n}{2^{k+1}}^i, 
\end{equation*}
so that $r_{n-1}=1$ and
\begin{equation*}
    r_k\ge\binom{2^n}{2^{1+1}}^i\to\infty 
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$) for $k=1,\dots,n-2$. So, $S_n\sim a_{n,n}+a_{n,n-1}=2a_{n,n}$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \log S_n=\log a_{n,n}+O(1). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
Next,
\begin{equation*}
    \log a_{n,n}=i\sum_{l=1}^n L_{n,l}=i\sum_{l=1}^{n-1} L_{n,l}, \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    L_{n,l}:=\log\binom{2^n}{2^l}. 
\end{equation*}
By Stirling's formula, $\log N!=N\log(N/e)+O(\log(N+1))$ for integers $N\ge1$. So, for $l=1,\dots,n-1$,
\begin{equation*}
    L_{n,l}=2^n K_{n,l}+O(n), \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    K_{n,l}:=K_{n,l;1}-K_{n,l;2}+K_{n,l;3}, \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    K_{n,l;1}:=2^{l-n}(n-l),\quad K_{n,l;2}:=\log(1-2^{l-n}),\quad K_{n,l;3}:=2^{l-n}\log(1-2^{l-n}).
\end{equation*}
Further,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} K_{n,l;1}=2 (1 - (n+1)2^{-n})\to2; \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} K_{n,l;2}=\sum_{l=-\infty}^{n-1} K_{n,l;2}-\sum_{l=-\infty}^0 K_{n,l;2}
    =-c_1+O(2^{-n})\to-c_1, \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{equation*}
where $c_1:=-\sum_{l=-\infty}^{n-1} K_{n,l;2}=-\sum_{j=1}^\infty\log(1-2^{-j})=1.7919\dots$;
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} K_{n,l;3}=\sum_{l=-\infty}^{n-1} K_{n,l;3}-\sum_{l=-\infty}^0 K_{n,l;3}
    =-c_2+O(2^{-2n})\to-c_2, \tag{7}\label{7}
\end{equation*}
where $c_2:=-\sum_{l=-\infty}^{n-1} K_{n,l;3}=-\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}\log(1-2^{-j})=0.63556\dots$.

Collecting \eqref{1}--\eqref{7}, we get
\begin{equation*}
    \log S_n\sim c\,i\,2^n,
\end{equation*}
where $c:=2+c_1-c_2=3.1563\dots$.

Answer (score 3):

For $$A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{l=1}^k\binom{2^n}{2^l}$$ it *seems* that
$$\log(\log(A_n))\sim \alpha +n \,\log(2) \qquad \qquad  \alpha \sim -0.383$$